# AngularJS : ng-repeat orderby error in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that creates a list, I'm trying to get the column sorting to work, so I created another directive for sorting the columns.

I get this error in the console while I'm trying to set up an orderby filter on that list:

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/$injector/unpr?p0=orderbyFilterProvider

here's my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SiBDuylEv1LUCuWCv5Ep?p=preview

here's where the orderby is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="column in columns">
            <sort-by onsort="onSort" sortdir=filterCriteria.sortDir sortedby=filterCriteria.sortedBy sortvalue="{{column.value}}">{{column.title}}</sort-by>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in set | orderby:sortBy:reverse" ng-class="getClass(item)" ng-click="selectItem(item,$event,$index)" ng-dblclick="details(item)">
        <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{item[column.value]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The "B" in `orderBy` is capital :)

Comment: I just broke my keyboard with my head. (Not really, but that really was the issue)